# Retrieve matching strings from text file

Tags: python, regex

I have the following text file and I want to retrieve the numbers in brackets

```
ID&number:Track_number(12930)_
ID&number:Track_number(394839)_
ID&number:Track_number(958236)_
```

So I've tried this

```
 import re

 file = open("text.txt", "r")
 text = file.read()
 file.close()
 pattern = re.compile(ur'Track_number(.*)_', re.UNICODE)
 string = pattern.search(text).group(1)
 print string
```

But it only displays the first result : `(12930)`.
I was wondering if it was possible to have a list of all the matching results.
Thanks

Comment: Yes, replace `search` with `findall`.

Comment: Oh, thank you. Solved my problem. Just, how can I remove the brackets ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) for example

```
>>> re.findall('\((\d+)\)', text)
['12930', '394839', '958236']
```

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was searching for.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is replace that `search` with `findall`. This will produce a `list` of all the matches.